# SQLAlchemy verify SSL connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, ssl, sqlalchemy

I would like to verify the SSL connection that SQLAlchemy sets up when using `create_engine` to connect to a PostgreSQL database. For example, if I have the following Python 3 code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:******@someserver:5432/somedb"

conn_args = {
    "sslmode": "verify-full",
    "sslrootcert": "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",
}

engine = create_engine(conn_string, connect_args=conn_args)
```

I know that I can print the contents of `engine.__dict__`, but it doesn't contain any information about the SSL settings (TLS version, cipher suite, etc) that it's using to connect:

```
{
    '_echo': False,
    'dialect': <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x7f988a217978>,
    'dispatch': <sqlalchemy.event.base.ConnectionEventsDispatch object at 0x7f988938e788>,
    'engine': Engine(postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:******@someserver:5432/somedb),
    'logger': <Logger sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (DEBUG)>,
    'pool': <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7f988a238c50>,
    'url': postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:******@someserver:5432/somedb
}
```

I know I can do something like `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_ssl;`, but does the SQLAlchemy engine store this kind of information as a class attribute / method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't use postgres so hopefully this holds true for you.

SQLAlchemy takes the info that you provide in the url and passes it down to the underlying dbapi library that is also specified in the url, in your case it's psycopg2.

Your `engine` instance only connects to the database when needed, and sqlalchemy just passes the connection info along to the driver specified in the url which returns a connection that sqlalchemy uses.

Forgive that this is mysql, but should be fundamentally the same for you:

```
>>> engine
Engine(mysql+mysqlconnector://test:***@localhost/test)
>>> conn = engine.connect()
>>> conn
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x000001614ACBE2B0>
>>> conn.connection
<sqlalchemy.pool._ConnectionFairy object at 0x000001614BF08630>
>>> conn.connection.connection
<mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x000001614AB7E1D0>
```

Calling `engine.connect()` returns a `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection` instance that has a [`connection property`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/8eaccf16aca90ef09e8e39cd06940ac8a51b5b38/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L370) for which the docstring says:

> The underlying DB-API connection managed by this Connection.

However, you can see from above that it actually returns a `sqlalchemy.pool._ConnectionFairy` object which from it's docstring:

> Proxies a DBAPI connection...

Here is the [`__init__()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/8eaccf16aca90ef09e8e39cd06940ac8a51b5b38/lib/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py#L715-L718) method of the connection fairy, and as you can see it has a `connection` attribute that is the actual underlying dbapi connection.

```
def __init__(self, dbapi_connection, connection_record, echo):
    self.connection = dbapi_connection
    self._connection_record = connection_record
    self._echo = echo
```

As to what info is available on the dbapi connection object, it depends on the implementation of that particular driver. E.g psycopg2 connection objects have an [`info`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.info) attribute:

> A [`ConnectionInfo`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.ConnectionInfo) object exposing information about the native libpq
>   connection.

That `info` object has attributes such as [`ssl_in_use`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.ConnectionInfo.ssl_in_use):

> True if the connection uses SSL, False if not.

And [`ssl_attribute`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.ConnectionInfo.ssl_attribute):

> Returns SSL-related information about the connection.

So you don't have to dig too deep to get at the actual db connection to see what is really going on.

Also, if you want to ensure that all client connections are ssl, you can always [`force them to`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8580/force-postgresql-clients-to-use-ssl).

Comment: Hi the last link is to force PostgreSQL clients to use SSL, how can we force MySQL client to use ssl? (With Python code specifically)

Comment: @Cecilia have you had a look at [`--ssl-mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-options.html#option_general_ssl-mode)? How that is configured through python will depend on your driver. If mysqlclient, `ssl-mode` is a keyword argument to the [`connect()`](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#functions-and-attributes) function.

Comment: @SuperShot Hi thanks, I uses `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` to connect to the database, should I use `ssl-mode`? I raised a separate question for verifying TLS using wireshark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160487/how-to-use-wireshark-to-verify-tlsv1-2-for-an-aws-aurora-mysql-database Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: To continue the comment above - (My driver is MySQL)

Answer (score 2):

Here´s a quick and dirty of what SuperShoot spelled out in detail:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> db_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:******@someserver:5432/somedb"
>>> db = create_engine(db_string)
>>> conn = db.connect()
>>> conn.connection.connection.info.ssl_in_use
```

Should return True if using SSL.

Comment: Hi the last line gave me error `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'ssl_in_use'`, Is there a way we can see which TLS version it' using? I want to verify the connection is using `TLSv1.2`.

Comment: When I do this, I get `psycopg2.NotSupportedError: 'ssl_in_use' not available in libpq < 9.5`...

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for **PostgreSQL** and **pg8000**, see the [pg8000 docs](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#connect-to-postgresql-over-ssl).

For SSL defaults, it is:

```py
import sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, connect_args={'ssl_context':True})
```