# How do I include SSL credentials in a SQLAlchemy connection string? And which should I include?

Tags: python, azure, ssl, sqlalchemy

I have a Python script written to connect to a SQL database in Azure, and I am getting the error below:

> 9002 (28000): SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options
>   and retry.

Clearly I need to include SSL credentials, but I'm unsure of how to do this given the rest of the formatting of my config file.

I currently have a dictionary with the database access credentials in it formatted as `'key' : 'value'`.

The SSL arguments I've seen seem to go in additional dictionaries or are non-string variables. Anyway, I just need someone to show me...

1. how to format it, and
2. examples of what they look like (ssl_ca, ssl_cert, and ssl_key)

Here is the dictionary in my config file, with the actual names of things of course changed.

```py
config = {
'user': 'username@database',
'password':'mypassword',
'host':'hostname.database.windows.net',
'database':'databasename'
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy verify SSL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267373/sqlalchemy-verify-ssl-connection)

Comment: @EdekiOkoh No, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: please include some samples of your code

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992181/6560549

Comment: Thanks @SuperShoot, but are all of those ('cert', 'key', and 'ca') required SSL arguments? I am able to connect using PyMySQL with just the 'cert' filepath. The issue is I specifically need to make use of SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connect_args = {
            "ssl": {
                "ssl_ca": "path of ssl cert"
            }
        }
engine = create_engine(dbstring, connect_args=connect_args)
```